# In C++, how can I make a questions that only accepts 2 letters as answers?

Tags: c++

I'm making a survey with a a struct and I'm trying to ask the user if he is male or female answering only with M or F. I used while to make the program re-ask the question if the user introduces a no acceptable answer but I ended up with an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
cout << "Introduce your genre (M or F)";
cin >> p[i].sex;
while  (p[i].sex !=M || p[i].sex !=F){
        cout << "Introduce your genre using M or F ";
        cin >> p[i].sex;
}
```

This is just a part of the whole code, but thats where I'm having problems.

Comment: Just read the input. If its not `M` or `F`, re-prompt the user.

Comment: You want && not ||.

Comment: `p[i].sex !=M` is true if the value is `F`, and `p[i].sex !=F` is true if the value is `M`.

Answer (score 3):

How can `p[i].sex` be *both* `M` and `F`?

Did you want `p[i].sex !=M && p[i].sex !=F`?

Also, consider using a `do` `while` loop instead so you can put the condition check at the end, which will avoid your having to write `cin` twice in your code.

Comment: I think I'm confused, doesnt || means "OR" and && "and"? Tried with && and its working fine now,

Comment: Yes `||` does indeed mean "or". But you seem to be misunderstanding what "or" actually means in this context.

Comment: Yes, just facepalmed myself right now, I dont know how I couldnt see it, thanks for the help!